# WordPress - Set 2 headers in one website

Tags: php, wordpress

i have to header like.

```
  header-first.php
  header-second.php
```

i create two template like first and second. when the first template is load then i want to load header-first.php and this is working. then second like first.

i have problem with when i load second template then the `header-second.php` is load is working but not when i go to any page then i want to load `header-second.php` but not it load `header.php`.

when i load a second template then the header-second.php is loaded working. now i going any page and view post then the header.php file is load i want to load header-second.php file. please help how can i set globally.

i try to set globally in function.php like.

```
global $header;

if(is_page_template('page-second.php')){
   header = 'second';
}else if(is_page_template('page-first.php')){
   header = 'first';
}
```

it working it return only template page is load.

when i try to load any other like about page it return `''` value. it not return any value.

i want to second whenever the first template is not visit.

thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your problem. Can you try explaining it again? You have 2 header files. When do you want to load header-first.php and when do you want to load header-second.php?

Comment: @NathanDawson when i load a second template then the header-second.php is loaded working. now i going any page and view post then the header.php file is load i want to load header-second.php file. please help how can i set globally.

Comment: Please clarify 'a second template'. You've built a theme and activated it, correct? Is second template a custom template file you've created and selected for a page?

Comment: @NathanDawson yes you got it. i create page for custom template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each template file such as page.php, single.php, archive.php, etc, will have `get_header()` at the top of it.

This function loads the header (header.php).

If you pass in a string as the first argument it will try to load `header-{argument}.php` and if not found it will load header.php.

Anywhere you want to load `header-second.php` you need to change `get_header();` to `get_header( 'second' );`

There is an action that fires when this function runs but there's no filter so you can't override it globally like you're attempting to do. Instead you need to update the template files individually with the function I showed you above.

To summarise change:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

To:

```
<?php get_header( 'second' ); ?>
```

Further reading: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header

Comment: yes i know that but how can i set globally. to header name. when i load second template then i go anywhere in site then i want to pass $header = 'second'; and load second header. but i try to set in functions.php file like global $header; but it overwrite when i load any other page.

Comment: OK you need to either set a session or a cookie when a user loads the template and add a conditional for it.